# Using OR and command substitution

Tags: grep

The following command works as expected...

```
tail /var/log/mysqld.log | grep `date '+%y%m%d' --date='1 day ago'`
```

But this does not...

```
tail /var/log/mysqld.log | grep (`date '+%y%m%d' --date='1 day ago'` | `date '+%y%m%d'`)
```

I want to return the lines having yesterday OR today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tail /var/log/mysqld.log | grep -e `date '+%y%m%d' --date='1 day ago'` -e `date '+%y%m%d'`
```